# How to migrate eclipse Juno workspace to Kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I have installed Kepler yesterday, but I want to use the old workspace instead of creating from scratch.

Is there any way to migrate eclipse Juno workspace to Kepler ?

Comment: Just open the same workspace

Comment: I was able to open my juno workspace in kepler without any problems. Making a backup copy before will be a good idea though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It basically depends on the plugins used by the projects in your workspace. If you use a standard Eclipse configuration there shouldn't be any problem, just open workspace, close all projects and open them again. If it doesn't work try cleaning them up.

Comment: Also this would help if you have JDT plug ins http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fporting%2Feclipse_3_9_porting_guide.html